# Java ConnectionException Server - Client Chat

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client

I'm not that good in Java so I'm still learning. I wanted to write a simple server client chat (multithreaded) but I got stuck...
After I added the threads my client isn't working anymore. So I start the server and the client and it takes 1 to 3 seconds till the client crashes... Error below
When my server was just an echo server it worked fine but after adding the threads there is this problem!

Java code client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int port = 40960;
        String host = "127.0.0.1";
        String newline = "\n";
        String clientname = "Jonathan";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            Socket client = new Socket(host, port);

            System.out.println("client started");

            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String i = input.nextLine();

            writer.write(clientname + ": " + i + newline);
            writer.flush();

            String s = null;

            while((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(s);

            }

            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();

        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    }

}
```

ConnectionException

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:25)
```

Server code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int port = 40480;
        int max = 10;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(max);

        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.print("server started");

            while(true) {

                try {
                    Socket client = server.accept();
                    executor.execute(new Handler(client));

                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

I really don't know what the problem is...
Hope you can help me! Thanks!!!

Comment: please post the server code too !

Comment: Done! You want to see Handler.java too?

Comment: yes, include Handler.

Comment: your server is listening on 409_6_0 and your client is connecting to 409_8_0.

Comment: Server runs on Port 40480 and client trys to connect to 40960 ...

Comment: Oh I didn't see that! Ok Thanks!!

Comment: PORT_NUMBER must be same for connecting. And for better practice introduce PORT_NUMBER as a static final keyword.